# Full height listView in Titanium (Android/iOS)

Tags: android, ios, listview, titanium

I am developing an multi-platform App for iOS and Android in Titanium Studio. I need to spread listView in Windows like this:

[image: what I mean]

Image, "Some text" and Footer with button should have static height (depended on height of its (sub)elements) and the remaining part of screen will be listView.

Is it possible? How? I tried to make tableView, or tried to detect height of the screen also, but with no luck.

Now I'm tring:

```
body = Ti.UI.createView({
            width:'100%',
            height:'100%',
            bottom: 0,
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            layout:'vertical',
                        borderColor: '#000000',
            borderWidth: 2,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
    });

....



  subbody = Ti.UI.createView({
                height:200,
                layout:'vertical',
                borderColor: '#000000',
                borderWidth: 2,
                bottom: 0,
        });


    var createButton = new Ti.UI.createButton({
        id:'createButton',
        title: 'Vytvorit novy', 
        bottom: 0   
    });
    var notfoundLabel = new Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: "Nebolo najdene",
        height: '100',
        width: '100%'
    });
    subbody.add(createButton);
    subbody.add(notfoundLabel); 
    body.add(subbody);
```

But it looks like (i have one more element on top (IMAGE)):

[image: how it looks like]

Comment: I found the problem with:
layout: 'vertical', but now it overflows through

Answer (score 0):

As you said that some text and Footer have a static height,you should set top and bottom of listview . In this way you can set listview in remaining area.

Comment: you should not use layout property for body object because then bottom property will not work so just remove layout property for body and then try....